# How do I use while statement in rock paper scissor

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
print("Let's play another game:\n\nRock, Paper & Scissors")

print("""Instead of Rock we choose: r 

Instead of Paper we choose: p

Instead of Scissors we choose: s\n""")

user1 = input("user1 -> ")

user2 = input("user2 -> ")

print()

if user1=="r":

  if user2=="r":

    print("ting tong! match draw")

  elif user2=="p":

    print("user1","\033[031m""looses""\033[0m","user2","\033[032m""win""\033[0m","by covering the rock with paper")

  elif user2=="s":

    print("user2","\033[031m""looses""\033[0m","user1","\033[032m""win""\033[0m","by smashing the scissors with rock")

  else:

    print("\033[030m""Invalid Move""\033[0m")

elif user1=="p":

  if user2=="r":

    print("user2","\033[031m""looses""\033[0m","user1","\033[032m""win""\033[0m","by covering the rock with paper")

  elif user2=="p":

    print("Ka Chaow, Match Draw")

  elif user2=="s":

    print("user1","\033[031m""looses""\033[0m","user2","\033[032m""win""\033[0m","by cutting the paper with scissors")

  else:

    print("\033[030m""Invalid Move""\033[0m")

elif user1=="s":

  if user2=="r":

    print("user1","\033[031m""looses""\033[0m","user2","\033[032m""win""\033[0m","by smashing the scissors with rock")

  elif user2=="p":

    print("user2","\033[031m""looses""\033[0m","user1","\033[032m""win""\033[0m","by cutting the paper with scissors")

  elif user2=="s":

    print("Slash match draw")    

  else:

    print("\033[030m""Invalid Move""\033[0m")
```

Comment: What do you want the `while` to do?

Comment: by winning either of the users it should ask whether we want to play again or terminate the game without going into an infinite loop.

Comment: You should try that yourself, and if it doesn't work then update this question with your new code and explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To repeat the game many times, you can easily wrap the whole code inside a while statement and also add an exit key like

```
char = ''
while True:
 # Put your code here
 char = input('Do you want to continue y/n')
 if ( char == 'n' ) :
   break
```

So if the user input a character `n` then the program will exit, else it will create a new game!

Comment: The OP has clearly labelled this question as `python`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play indefinitely you can put all this code in `while(true):`
If you want the first player to reach X points to win and end the game you can do this before your code :

```
points=[0,0]
while not(X in points):
   your code...
```

`and whenever a player wins, increase his points total by 1 like this:

```
points[0]+=1
```

(this makes player 1 have 1 more point)